# How to print a response from a GET that link two entities/tables?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, orm

Hello =] I was tasked with something due to an activity, and don't know how to make it work, hope someone could help :P

I have three entities: '**person**', '**paper**' and '**property**'.

Person id is '**persCod**', papers id is '**serialNumber**', and properties has both 'persCod' and 'serialNumber' as ids (**composite primary keys**).

The idea is that **a single person** (persCod) **can have multiple properties**, each property being a given paper.

When sending a GET request to find a certain property, I want the response body to contain all that property's info + the name of the 'paper' which serialNumber equals the one from the found property. I need to search the property through its 'persCod' tho.

**Person**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person{
  @Id
  private Long persCod;
  private String name;
}
```

**Paper**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "PAPERS")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Paper{
  @Id
  private Integer serialNumber;
  private String paperName;
}
```

**Property**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROPERTY")
@IdClass(IdProperty.class)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Property {
  @Id
  private Long persCod;
  @Id
  private Integer serialNumber;
  private String paperName;
  private String description;

}
```

**What I need is, when sending a GET request to `localhost:8080/property/{persCodA}`, to get a response like this:**

```
{
serialNumber: 101010,
paperName: "[the name of the paper which serialNumber also is 101010]",
description: the given description
},
{
serialNumber: 030303,
paperName: "[the name of the paper which serialNumber also is 030303]",
description: the given description
}
```

Don't know if I managed to explain it well enough, but would be glad to get some guidance =]

Comment: Your query is based around api routes and ORM and not SQL.  Doing this in SQL is very straightforward doing it with an ORM is different.  You should adjust the tags to get target the correct audience.

Comment: Or in short as the person (Tianhong Yu) supplying the correct answer below is saying, An "enitiy class" is a set of properties variables that map to a column-"field" in a database and has the "complete collection" of the SQL query fields to be returned from the query as properties, and an enitiy is a "template" for the DTO Data Transfer Object class instance (actually holds the returned data) and Data Access Object class instance (obtains or replaces DTO data in that DTO instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First, all properties that belong to that person are queried via their primary key, persCod.
- Second, then based on this set of properties, the loop queries the paperName of the associated paper via the field serialNumber of each property.
- Third, combine the results of your query and return them.

---

- Option one:

```sql
-- Use join query
SELECT pro.serialNumber, pap.paperName, pro.description
FROM propertie pro
    LEFT JOIN pape pap
    ON pro.serialNumber = pap.serialNumber
WHERE pro.persCod = #{persCod};
```

- Option two:

```java
public List<PropertyDTO> listByPersCode(String persCode) {
    // 1. query property table
    List<PropertyDO> propertyDOs = propertyDAO.selectByPersCode(persCode);

    // 2. query paper table
    List<String> serialNumbers = propertyDOs.stream()
            .map(PropertyDO::getSerialNumber)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<PaperDO> PaperDOs = paperDAO.selectBatchBySerialNumber(serialNumbers);

    // 3. combine the results
    Map<String, String> map = PaperDOs.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(PaperDO::getSerialNumber, PaperDO::getPaperName));

    return propertyDOs.stream()
            .map(propertyConverter::toDTO)  // copy object's fields
            .peek(e -> e.setPaperName(map.get(e.getSerialNumber())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```